# Non-Uniform Traffic among Services (SOA)

Tags: soa

I want to implement SOA in my application. It will consist of services of several levels (Level 1 is top level service, level 2 are services needed by level 1 services, and so on).
Some of low level services will have higher probability of being accessed, therefore causes the traffic to be more dense compared to those on the top level.

Is there any way, like intelligent routing or algo or technique to cope with this non-uniform traffic to get the best performance in this architecture?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are mistaking layers for services. Note that services incur (relatively) a lot of overhead (serialization, deserialization, security (authentication, authorization, maybe encryption), network etc.) Is this something you want to do all over the place? (also see [nano-services](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Nanoservices.pdf) anti-pattern)

To your question - you can deploy multiple copies of services, pay attention to store their state externally (cache, db etc.) and put a load balancer before them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. I was thinking of the same concept, just previously I didnt know it is called load balancer...

Comment: Another option is to put a queue in the middle and have worker instances that pull from that queue. Then you can have different number of instances per service (see decoupled invocation http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/decoupled-invocation/ and service instance http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/service-instance/ patterns)